# How to scrape very many pages from a single website?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

Please someone run this code. Then advice me on how to speed up scraping of these pages. There are over 20,000 pages meaning i would take a couple of days to finish. I am requesting for a better approach.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15"
]

driver_path = '/users/tosh/downloads/chromedriver'
user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)

main_url = 'https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/Chome/pencarian/'
driver.get(main_url)
time.sleep(5)

search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-top"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div/div[3]/div/button')
search_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

max_retries = 3
href_set = set()
page = 1

while True:
    for _ in range(max_retries + 1):
        try:
            section = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="pageload"]')
            elements = section.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="list-group-item"]/a[contains(., "Lihat")]')
            if not elements:
                break  # No more "Lihat" links, indicating end of data

            for element in elements:
                href = element.get_attribute('href')
                href_set.add(href)

            href_list = list(href_set)
            href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
            with open('output_hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
                for href in href_list:
                    file.write(href + '\n')

            next_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//ul[@class="pagination pull-left"]/li/a[text()="{page + 1}"]')
            next_page_link.click()
            time.sleep(5)

            page += 1
            break
        except (WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
            if _ < max_retries:
                print(f"Retrying page {page}, Attempt {_ + 1}")
                continue
            else:
                print(f"Unable to navigate to page {page} after {max_retries} attempts")
                break


href_list = list(href_set)
href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
with open('output_hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
    for href in href_list:
        file.write(href + '\n')

driver.quit()
```

You will notice i am resaving on two output files. thats because i want to save as i scrape. for every page scraped, save the data.

the part below is working fine but can only scrape one page at a time. Making it very slow because when will i reach the 20,000th page. I am using 3 maximum retries incase the page does not respond within the first attempt.

```
while True:
    for _ in range(max_retries + 1):
        try:
            section = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="pageload"]')
            elements = section.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="list-group-item"]/a[contains(., "Lihat")]')
            if not elements:
                break  # No more "Lihat" links, indicating end of data

            for element in elements:
                href = element.get_attribute('href')
                href_set.add(href)

            href_list = list(href_set)
            href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
            with open('output_hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
                for href in href_list:
                    file.write(href + '\n')

            next_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//ul[@class="pagination pull-left"]/li/a[text()="{page + 1}"]')
            next_page_link.click()
            time.sleep(5)

            page += 1
            break
        except (WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
            if _ < max_retries:
                print(f"Retrying page {page}, Attempt {_ + 1}")
                continue
            else:
                print(f"Unable to navigate to page {page} after {max_retries} attempts")
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion

1. Try to reduce writing to a file only once (Writing/Opening to a file is slow and you are doing it at every pages). Save the data in a variable and write it to a file once you are done (or if a certain page is reached - like every 100 pages save it)
2. Try to use BeautifulSoup if you can, Selenium is much slower compared to bs4. bs4 is good if you only need to get data and doesn't need much automation.